# htaccess rewrite issue while testing on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm running OSX (10.6) with Apache with .htaccess enabled.

In the htaccess file I have the code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+) index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

This runs perfectly on my external server and redirects nicely to index.php?page=whatever

However when testing locally from `localhost/~james/In%20Progress/Vila%20Maninga/page/whatever` I get redirected to `localhost/~james/Users/James/Sites/In%20Progress/Vila%20Maninga/index.php?page=whatever`. For some reason '`Users/James/Sites/`' is being added.

Does anyone why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is the problem, but try adding this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
```

(substitute `/` with whatever path you like)